# How to Access Visual Studio Development Server from a Virtual PC?

Tags: internet-explorer, virtual-machine, vpc

I've installed the WindowsXP_IE6.0 vpc from here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575

I have an asp.net application and ran it locally:

```
http://localhost:22159/Pages/Home.aspx
```

How could I access this application from the Windows XP vpc?

I've enabled Shared Networking (NAT) for the Virtual Machine and it can only access the internet.

When navigating to the above application page, it gives me the error message that "The page cannot be displayed"

I think the reason is that localhost refers to the vm localhost rather than the host. I also tried it with the host computer name but the same error

```
http://hostComputerName:22159/Pages/Home.aspx
```

How could I configure this?

I may have to setup the application on IIS then it may help accessing it from the vm; not sure.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here: http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.com/2011/08/connect-to-host-iis-from-virtual-pc.html

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to get the ASP.NET development to serve pages to remote machines either (assuming that this is because this product is for development and not intended for production websites) and normally setup a website under IIS to host the application in.

Comment: I saw a workaround here which uses port forwarding: http://geekswithblogs.net/imilovanovic/archive/2010/04/26/working-with-visual-studio-web-development-server-and-ie6-in.aspx but it requires that my host machine to have a STATIC ip address that I can't do; I'll try setting up the application in IIS and see how it goes from there.

Comment: the application is in IIS and its address is again a localhost address. same issue; how to access it from the VM?

Comment: You should be able to browse using the IP and/or machine name of the host running IIS. At the command prompt on the VM enter: nslookup <name_of_your_machine>. If this returns the IP address then you are good to go using HTTP://<name_of_your_machine> otherwise you have to use HTTP://<ip_address>. Also verify everything is running first on localhost using IIS

Comment: My VM can't access the Host machine using http://<name_of_your_machine> nor can it using the ip address of the host machine. it displays the same error message as mentioned above. How to configure it so that it can access it? thanks.

Comment: NAT had to be configured for the VPC.